# If $f$ is integrable on every set of finite measure then $f=f_1+f_2$ where $f_1$ is integrable, $f_2$ is bounded

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb R$ and integrable on every subset of $\mathbb R$ with  finite measure, the claim is that it can be written as a sum of an integrable function $f_1$ and a bounded one $f_2$.

My first idea was to use the intervals $[n,n+1]$ somehow. But then I noted that this might be not enough: consider for example $e^x$. For every such interval it is integrable, however it can't be written as such a sum. If it could, then $f_2 \leq M$ for some $M$ and for $e^x>M$ we would have $f_1 > e^x-M$ and therefore $f_1$ would not be integrable.

But this example leaves only two options: either the claim is false, or $e^x$ does not have the property that it is integrable in every set of finite measure. So I thought about it and, if my calculations are correct, then if $q_n$ is an enumeration of the rational numbers, the set $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(q_n-\frac{1}{2^n},q_n+\frac{1}{2^n})$ has finite measure, while the integral of $e^x$ over $A$ is infinite. Therefore the claim may be true.

Another intuitive idea that I had, was that if $f$ has such a property, then there must exist a number $M$ such that the integral of $f$ over the set $\{x\in\mathbb R : |f(x)|>M\}$ sould be finite. But I couldn't prove such a thing. Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**
I think I found a proof that this is true. Take the sequence of sets $A_n = \{x\in \mathbb R: |f(x)| > 2^n\}$. These are all measurable because $f$ is measurable. Suppose that they all have infinite measure. Then, choose $B_n \subset A_n$ with $m(B_n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$ and all $B_n$'s pairwise disjoint. Then, $m(\bigcup B_n) = 1$ but $\int_{\bigcup B_n} |f| dm = \sum \int_{B_n} |f| dm > \sum \int_{B_n} 2^n dm = \sum 2^n m(B_n) = \sum 1 = \infty$ which contradicts the fact that $f$ is integrable on every set of finite measure. Therefore there is an $k$ such that $A_k$ has finite measure. Define $f_2(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       f(x) & : x \in \mathbb R \setminus A_k\\
       0 & : x \in A_k
     \end{array}
   \right.$
and
$f_1(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : x \in \mathbb R \setminus A_k\\
       f(x) & : x \in A_k
     \end{array}
   \right.$
then obviously $f=f_1+f_2$, $f_2 \leq 2^k$ thus $f_2$ is bounded and $\int_{\mathbb R} |f_1| dm = \int_{A_k} |f_1| dm = \int_{A_k} |f| dm < \infty$ because $m(A_k)$ is finite. Is this correct?

Comment: For every $ L^s $ function the statement is true....